# Developing an API for a USB connected Glucometer

Tags: usb, device

I have a ReliOn Glucometer that can be connected to a Windows PC via USB.  [Glucometer Details Here](http://www.relion.com/diabetes/confirm).  I have never tried this, but can someone point me in the right direction to go about connecting to a USB device (C# or Delphi) and pulling data from it?  I want to download the current test result and save off to a database to build log of test history.  I am a diabetic and I hate doing the tests everyday, but I realized if I can leverage this necessary evil with learning how to work with USB connected device, I at least can get some pleasure in knowing I made some good out of this.

Has anyone done this or something similar?  I know there is a website I can join and they have an OCX to do this.. but I don't want to put my info/data on a site, plus it misses the point - I want the challenge of doing this.

Any advice - directions where to start would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I would begin by looking at the USB device driver that comes with the software, especially the inf file. Is it HID or is it for a specific USB chipset, etc? Then look for a relevant development kit/info to take it from there.